# categories and sub-categories dropdown form

Tags: wordpress, categories

Please help me determine the correct code for my drop-down search form. I want to be able to populate from a drop down: Categories – Sub Categories - Sub Sub Categories – Sub Sub Sub Categories. Here is how the form is displaying: Select a state – Select a County – Select a City – Select a Zip Code.

Also, When I select the first category It immediately display results; is there a way to stop the results from displaying after selecting but only populate the next sub category, and add a submit button to the bottom of the form that will display results?

I’m a newbie and I don’t mind paying a fee for your time. Thanks a lot for your help,

John

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complicated task:

1. You need to identify a data source, such as [this one](http://gomashup.com/cms/usa_zipcode_json), for a list of states, counties, cities and zipcodes in the U.S. provided in XML/JSON format.
2. You need to create a [jQuery script](http://blogaddition.com/2013/01/country-state-city-dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-and-ajax/) that shows the right select dropdown depending on the prior section (using the data feeds above).

It's impossible to show an example here, because it depends on the language that you want to use, data sources, etc. If you don't have these expertise, you can post the job on any number of job sites.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Justin. I found the Perfect example of what I'm trying to do and by the way I'm using WordPress Platform under PHP/MYSQL.

Comment: http://vikku.info/programming/geodata/get-state-county-city-list-of-united-states.htm